# Responsive Image without CSS otherwise messes HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I have a responsive web page which inside a Div tag i have an IMG tag as follows:

```
<div id="frontPage">
<img src="img/bg.jpg" height="500px" width="100%">
 </div>
```

It runs great on desktop, However, Using CSS with @media would be great if i didnt touch this code in the Div tag above. When i comment or delete this code inside the Div tag and use CSS to add the same image using CSS, It appears zoomed in and ugly and not like it is in Plain old Static HTML so its why i am trying to avoid using CSS and instead a different way like using Javascript possibly.

This is the code i use in CSS which comes out ugly:

```
#frontPage{
max-width: 100%;
height: 450px;
background: url(img/bg.jpg) no-repeat left 0px ;
}
```

It comes out Zoomed in and ugly and well i tried everything i can including changing the height and width like in the IMG tag and its frustating that it wont come out as it does in the IMG tag in the html code.

Is there any possible way of doing this Using Javascript where the Phseudo code will go ass follow:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

   //Phseudo Code

   if (mobileScreenSize == 480){
      //Mobile Image
      <img src="img/mobileImage.jpg" height="500px" width="100%">
    }
    else
    {
      //Regular desktop image
      <img src="img/bg.jpg" height="500px" width="100%">
     }
  </script>
```

I dont know what else to try, and i want to avoid using the CSS since it doesnt seem or i donnt know how to make it come out as it does using the HTMl IMG tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to use CSS to modify the background image, you need to set the "background-size" property. For example,

```
#frontPage{
max-width: 100%;
height: 450px;
background: url(img/bg.jpg) no-repeat left 0px ;
background-size: 100% 450px;
}
```

If you want to take the javascript approach, then that's also fine and the way you add an image to a div is by doing something like this.

```
var elem = document.createElement("img");
elem.setAttribute("src", "img/bg.jpg");
elem.setAttribute("height", "450px");
elem.setAttribute("width", "100%");
document.getElementById("frontPage").appendChild("elem");
```

Comment: Great, The CSS method worked, I can't believe i forgot that Little piece of code in the CSS body "background-size", Thank you